# Slurred half circle symbol

Tags: notation, organ

As an organist-amateur I recently bought "An Easy Bach Organ Album". In BWV 691 there's a symbol which looks like a half of a circle, or a small letter *c*. Moreover, the symbol is connected with the next note.
How is the symbol called and what does it mean?

Please find the 8th bar of the BWV 691.
[image: BWV 691, 8th bar, from An Easy Bach Organ Album, p. 26]

Comment: Thanks for the clear picture!  Too often here we see scores photographed in a dark room by a vibrating cell phone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "c" is a "slide", which would be played as F# G# A (starting on the beat). That would then be followed by the mordent, so the whole ornament would be F# G# A G# A played (approximately) as four 32nd-notes followed by a 16th.

But that sounds pretty crude musically, because the collision of the F# on the beat in the bass and treble.

The "slur" is probably intended to prolong the note *before* the ornament, which removes the weakness and would be played something like this. Of course ornaments are not meant to be played in strict time, and this implies a tempo slow enough to let all the notes "speak" properly, and let the listener hear the F# bass on the beat against the G# in the treble before the ornament starts.

[image]

A modern edition (Les Éditions Outremontaises) has this simpler version
[image]

[image]

The Bach-Gesellschaft Ausgabe edition has the "slur" but not the "slide", and does not have the G# grace note in Les Éditions Outremontaises.

There is a more longer and more elaborate version of the chorale prelude, BWV 691a, which has no ornament at all in the Bach-Gesellschaft Ausgabe edition.

So (as with all baroque ornaments) at the end of the day you play whatever version you prefer - and not necessarily the same version every time you play the piece.